# I already moved MySQL system files, but can't see them on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I try to export/import my 13GB sql-database but i couldnt do it, and then I moved from the old system (.frm and .ibd files) to my new. But on phpmyadmin I couldnt see my new tables.

What do I have to move too?  Or How can I move my 13GB database ?

I used that command to move:

```
rsync -avzP db root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/db1/
```

After moving from my old server to my new server, I use that to move files to my_database

```
mv /db1/ /var/lib/mysql/my_database/
```

and I can see the .frm and .ibd files on /var/lib/mysq/my_database/.

Now I realize that :

Some of tables are on phpmyadmin but they are 3 files on system (.MYD, .ibd, .frm) . Not has .MYD files not on phpmyadmin . But on my old doesnt has also the others ?

thanks for help

Comment: Have you reload mysql after copying files?

Comment: You mean "service mysql restart ? "

Comment: Yes. Thats what I mean. Or a `mysqladmin --reload` should do the same.

Comment: I did it but the result is same

Comment: both server has the same mysql version?

Comment: Yes they have the same mysql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54180/discussion-between-jens-and-muhammet-arslan).